# How to create write permissions for new SQL Server database file

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2016 running in a VM on Windows Server 2012 R2. The host is Windows 7.

On the VM local `C:` drive, I have mapped a shared network drive (`Z:\`) that points to another drive (`F:\`) on the host. I can access the `F:` drive from the VM in Windows explorer.

I am trying to create a new SQL Server datafile on the `F:` drive:

```
ALTER DATABASE AdventureWorksDW
ADD FILE
    (
        NAME = [FactResellerSales],
        FILENAME = 'Z:\SQL_files\AdventureWorksDW_FactResellerSales.ndf',
        SIZE = 100MB,
        MAXSIZE = 1GB,
        FILEGROWTH = 100MB
    )
TO FILEGROUP [FactResellerSales]
```

This fails with an error:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 112
> Directory lookup for the file "Z:\SQL_files\AdventureWorksDW_FactResellerSales.ndf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 5009, Level 16, State 8, Line 112
> One or more files listed in the statement could not be found or could not be initialized.

I cannot seem to figure out how to give SQL Server access to this drive.

When I right-click on the shared folder (`Z:`) there are no advanced sharing options (only General, Previous Versions, and Customize tabs).

Does anyone know what else I could do?

Thanks!
J

Answer (score 1):

Drive mappings in Windows are per-user, not system-wide.  You should use a UNC path instead of a drive letter mapping when creating a database on a file share.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/install-sql-server-with-smb-fileshare-as-a-storage-option?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

insteed of z:\   point to your computer name
like:

\\computername\SQL_files\AdventureWorksDW_FactResellerSales.ndf'

it will automatically point to your shared drive

Comment: Thank you Roya, That seems to work, but I am now getting an operating system 5 error now (Access Denied).  I can't seem to figure out how to give SQL Server the right access.  In the BOL documentation, I see "The SQL Server service account and SQL Server agent service account should have FULL CONTROL share permissions and NTFS permissions on the SMB share folders."  I am not versed in windows permissions.  Any odeas to point me in the right direction?  TIA

Comment: In shared folder , check both users  mssqlserver and mssqlagent have full permissions